# Create a new array from an array and a string using Map

Tags: javascript

I have an array which is:

```
let arr = [1, 10, 100];
```

and a string:

```
let str = 'name';
```

The intended result is to have an array like:

```
new_arr = [['name', 1], ['name', 10], ['name',100]];
```

I can easily achieve this with a for each but I was wondering what would be the best of doing it with the Map function. Any suggestion?

Comment: `var new_arr = arr.map(number => [str, number]);`

Comment: Since you're asking for the best way, what did your attempt to do this with `map()` look like? To see how the function works, here's a custom implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yo6ufbxj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using map:

```js
let arr = [1,10,100];

let string = 'name';

const newarr = arr.map(value => [string, value]);

console.log(newarr);
```